# Unclear why I lost -17 rep on a question

Tags: support

I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9418891/328397) and saw the following -17 points in my rep dashboard

[image]

I then looked at the question and saw that I only had one downvote

[image]

What could account for the lost rep?  The math doesn't add up since I had the -1 from a long time ago.

Comment: The good news is that losing -17 means you gained 17 rep!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since your question was migrated to Stack Overflow, it received:

1. 17 upvotes worth 85 reputation points.
2. 1 downvote, lowering it to 83
3. 100 points bounty you started: 83 - 100 = -17

Q.E.D.